# How to kill interval function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the snippet below. Is there a way to check whether the `setInterval()` is really killed or still running in background processing?

Technically what I need to do is killing the JS setInterval whenever the `.map` is not in the page. My understanding is the  `setInterval()` still running every 2 second just is not writing on the console because of `if` statement.

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    if ($(".map")[0]) {
      console.log("Map is in the Page");
    } else {
     //Stop Interval
    }
  }, 2000);
  
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".box").empty(); 
  }, 9000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="map">Map in Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to stop the execution of the intervalled function.

Here's an example:

```js
let i = 3;

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i > 0) {
    console.log("Running " + i--);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);

    console.log("Stopped");
  }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to kill an interval or timeout you should assign it to a variable for referencing. The specific functions are: clearInterval(*your interval reference variable name*) and clearTimeout(*your timeout reference variable name*).

```js
var yourInterval = setInterval(
  function() {

    console.log("Still running?"); //for testing purpose.

    if ($(".map")[0]) {
      console.log("Map is in the Page");
    } else {
      clearInterval(yourInterval); //it kills this interval, if the interval already terminated, it won't do anything harm, nor produce an error message in the browser console.
    }
  }, 2000);
  
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".box").empty(); 
  }, 9000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="map">Map in Here</div>
</div>
```